# Monotone Convergence Theorem - Bartle Elements of Real Analysis Book

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am not sure how the author went from this $x - l \leq x_n \leq x + l$ to this $x - l \leq sup\{x_n\} \leq x + l$, I boulded this part on the theorem for clarity.

Let $X = (x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers which is monotone increasing in the sense that $ x_1 \leq x_2 ...\leq x_n$

Then the sequence $X$ converges if and only if it is bounded, in which case $\lim(x_n) = \sup \{x_n\}$.

Proof. If  $x=\lim(x_n)$ and $l > 0$, then there exists a natural number $K(l)$ such that if $K(l)\leq$ n then

$\textbf{x - l $\leq$ x_n $\leq$ x + l}$

Since x is monotone, this relation yields

$x - l \leq\sup\{x_n\} \leq x + l$

....

---

Comment: FYI, there are several analysis books by Bartle. You should edit to indicate which one, and which section/page number.

Comment: Sorry I did not know that. I am editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be an increasing sequence of real numbers.

Let us also suppose that it is bounded.

Since the set $\{x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not empty and bounded, it admits a supremum, which we denote by $s$.

This means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow s - \varepsilon < x_{n_{\varepsilon}} \leq x_{n} \leq s < s + \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x_{n} - s| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $x_{n}\to s$.

Similar reasoning applies if the sequence $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is decreasing and bounded below.

In such case, the sequence $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $\inf\{x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

On the other hand, if the sequence converges to some $L\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is bounded.

Indeed, according to the definition of convergence, let $\varepsilon = 1$.

Then there corresponds $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{1} \Rightarrow |x_{n} - L| < 1 \Rightarrow |x_{n}| < |L| + 1
\end{align*}

Then it suffices to take $M = \max\{|x_{0}|,|x_{1}|,\ldots,|x_{n_{1}}|,|L| + 1\}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\sup\{x_n\}$. Since $(x_n)$ is monotone increasing, then for $l>0$, there exists an $N\geq 1$, such that $x_N > U - l$. If this were not the case, then it would imply that $x_N\leq U-l < U$ for all $N\geq 1$, which contradicts that $U$ is the least upper bound on $(x_n)$. Thus, we have that
$$
n\geq N \implies U - l < X_N \leq x_n < U + l \implies \lvert x_n - U \rvert \leq l.
$$
So $x_n\to U = x$ as $n\to \infty$.